# Different gutters with susy sass

Tags: sass, compass, susy-compass, susy

I have this susy settings:

```
$susy: (
  columns: 8,
  gutters: 1/4,  
  global-box-sizing: border-box,   
);
```

Sometimes I need different gutters instead 1/4.

See image for example:

[image]

And the code:

```
.wrap {  
  @include clearfix; 
  @include container (500px); 

  .box-1 {
    @include span(4 of 8);
  }
  .box-2 {
    @include span(4 of 8 last);
  }
  .box-3 {
    @include span(4 of 8 wide no-gutter);
  }
  .box-4 {
    @include span(4 of 8 last);
  }

  .box-5 {
    @include span(3.95 of 8 wide no-gutter);
  }

  .box-6 {
    @include span(4 of 8 last);
  }
}
```

I tried this without success:

```
@include span(4 of 8 wide (gutter-override: 2px));
```

I found a way to fix it but not if it is correct

```
@include span(3.95 of 8 wide no-gutter);
```

Thanks

Comment: What output did you get from `@include span(4 of 5 wide (gutter-override: 2px));` and what were you expecting?

Comment: I get `width: 83.33333%; float: left; margin-right: 2px;` which seems like what I'd expect.

Comment: With `@include span(2 of 4 wide (gutter-override: 2px));` I get: `width: 52.63158%;float: left;margin-right: 2px;` then the block 6 moves down , I need `width: 51.31579%;float: left;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the layout like this

```
@include with-layout(12 1/8 fluid float after) {

  .box-5 {
    @include span(2 of 12);
  }

  .box-6 {
    @include span(10 of 12 last);
  }

}
```

Where the **1/8** is the gutter width.

Comment: You mean: `.box-5 {@include gutters(3em);@include span(2 of 4);}` ?? yes, the box-5 changes its gutter but box-6 moves down because does not change its width

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
.box-5 {
   float:left;
   width: span(4 of 8 wide) - 1%;
}

.box-6 {
   float:right;
   width: span(4 of 8);
}
```